# oracle sql query check if the response is correctly related with the request

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a message transferring system.
In this system, a country (sender) sends a message to another (recipient), and the recipient responds to the initial sender with another message.

The msg_type of a message, indicating whether it is a request message or a response message.

```
WITH MSG_TYPES(MSG_TYPE_REQ, MSG_TYPE_RES) AS (
SELECT 'CD502C%', 'CD503C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CD510C%', 'CD591C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CD527C%', 'CD538C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CD540C%', 'CD545C%' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
 FROM MSG_TYPES;
```

It's important to note that the response message shares the same "mrn," "domain," and "env" with the request, and the "correl_id" of response is set to the "msg_id" of the sender.

I want to find only responses which have received for the same DOMAIN, MRN, ENV and the correl_id of the response is different from the msg_id of the request.

Case 1 : All requests messages are matched with the corresponding responses

```
WITH SAMPLE_DATA(ID, MSG_ID, MSG_TYPE, SENDER, RECIPIENT, CORREL_ID, MRN, DOMAIN, ENV, M_MIN_DATE)
AS (
SELECT 53, '2f5bbec582ff49728d712007e800a5320000018ceaddc90a', 'CD502C-MSG.ECS', 'LV', 'LT', '32344c545652343030303030304630314233000000000000', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('08-JAN-24 20.57.35', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 54, '4145532d32303234303130382d3030303030303031373533', 'CD503C-MSG.ECS', 'LT', 'LV', '2f5bbec582ff49728d712007e800a5320000018ceaddc90a', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('08-JAN-24 20.59.06', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 55, 'a60a0b09007446aa84d2d942a9f6dc600000018ceaea990f', 'CD502C-MSG.ECS', 'LV', 'LT', '32344c545652343030303030304630314233000000000000', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('08-JAN-24 21.11.35', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 56, '4145532d32303234303130382d3030303030303031373539', 'CD503C-MSG.ECS', 'LT', 'LV', 'a60a0b09007446aa84d2d942a9f6dc600000018ceaea990f', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('08-JAN-24 21.13.27', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 57, 'a0e56251c9304cf394f7fc8d393676360000018cece451c9', 'CD502C-MSG.ECS', 'LV', 'LT', '32344c545652343030303030304630314233000000000000', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('09-JAN-24 06.23.57', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 58, '4145532d32303234303130392d3030303030303030303537', 'CD503C-MSG.ECS', 'LT', 'LV', 'a0e56251c9304cf394f7fc8d393676360000018cece451c9', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('09-JAN-24 06.25.31', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL
), 
MSG_TYPES(MSG_TYPE_REQ, MSG_TYPE_RES) AS (
SELECT 'CD502C%', 'CD503C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CD510C%', 'CD591C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CD527C%', 'CD538C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CD540C%', 'CD545C%' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REQ.SENDER, REQ.MSG_TYPE AS "Request_MSG", REQ.MSG_ID AS "MSG_ID of the Request MSG",
      REQ.RECIPIENT, RES.CORREL_ID AS "CORREL_ID of the Response MSG",  coalesce(RES.msg_type,'') AS "Response_MSG", REQ.MRN, REQ.M_MIN_DATE
 FROM SAMPLE_DATA REQ 
      LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_DATA RES ON ( REQ.MRN = RES.MRN 
                                 AND REQ.DOMAIN = RES.DOMAIN
                                 AND REQ.ENV = RES.ENV) 
      INNER JOIN MSG_TYPES MSG ON (1=1)
WHERE 1=1
 AND REQ.RECIPIENT = 'LT'
 AND REQ.MSG_ID <> RES.CORREL_ID
 AND REQ.SENDER <> REQ.RECIPIENT
 AND REQ.M_MIN_DATE <= RES.M_MIN_DATE
 AND REQ.MSG_TYPE LIKE MSG_TYPE_REQ
 AND RES.MSG_TYPE LIKE MSG_TYPE_RES;
```

As we can see the message with id = 53 has as response the message with id=54 and the msg_id of request is the same with correl_id of response.
So, there is no error.
The same applies for 55 with 56 and 57 with 58

But executing the above query I get 3 rows , instead of 0 rows.

Case 2 : on this case the query works as expected

```
WITH SAMPLE_DATA(ID, MSG_ID, MSG_TYPE, SENDER, RECIPIENT, CORREL_ID, MRN, DOMAIN, ENV, M_MIN_DATE)
AS (
SELECT 60, '414d5120424741503220202020202020e4724a6565dfbe26', 'CD502C-MSG.ECS', 'BG', 'IT', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('15-DEC-23 13.34.24', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 61, '414d5120424741503220202020202020e4724a6569dfbe26', 'CD527C-MSG.ECS', 'BG', 'IT', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('15-DEC-23 13.35.21', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 62, '313730323634373334323434333839333832333034363136', 'CD503C-MSG.ECS', 'IT', 'BG', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('15-DEC-23 13.35.43', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 63, '313730323634373336313038323839343137393430353339', 'CD538C-MSG.ECS', 'IT', 'BG', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('15-DEC-23 13.36.02', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 64, '414d5120424741503220202020202020e4724a6579200628', 'CD518C-MSG.ECS', 'BG', 'IT', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('23-DEC-23 07.21.23', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL
), 
MSG_TYPES(MSG_TYPE_REQ, MSG_TYPE_RES) AS (
SELECT 'CD502C%', 'CD503C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CD510C%', 'CD591C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CD527C%', 'CD538C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CD540C%', 'CD545C%' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REQ.SENDER, REQ.MSG_TYPE AS "Request_MSG", REQ.MSG_ID AS "MSG_ID of the Request MSG",
      REQ.RECIPIENT, RES.CORREL_ID AS "CORREL_ID of the Response MSG",  coalesce(RES.msg_type,'') AS "Response_MSG", REQ.MRN, REQ.M_MIN_DATE
 FROM SAMPLE_DATA REQ 
      LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_DATA RES ON ( REQ.MRN = RES.MRN 
                                 AND REQ.DOMAIN = RES.DOMAIN
                                 AND REQ.ENV = RES.ENV) 
      INNER JOIN MSG_TYPES MSG ON (1=1)
WHERE 1=1
 AND REQ.RECIPIENT = 'IT'
 AND REQ.MSG_ID <> RES.CORREL_ID
 AND REQ.SENDER <> REQ.RECIPIENT
 AND REQ.M_MIN_DATE <= RES.M_MIN_DATE
 AND REQ.MSG_TYPE LIKE MSG_TYPE_REQ
 AND RES.MSG_TYPE LIKE MSG_TYPE_RES;
```

2 rows are returned correctly.

The condition AND REQ.RECIPIENT = 'IT' will be on a loop or another ‘WITH’ clause, for this reason on the first query it is defined as ‘LT’ and then as ‘IT’.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem either with your sample data or with your join conditions for linking REQ with RES. For LT REQ_ID 53 is matched with RES_ID 56 and 58. Also your RES_ID 58 is matched with REQ_ID 53 and 55. For IT matches are ok.
I put all the sample data together and changed the code a bit for readability but the result is the same as with your code.
Below you can see that there is are problem of double matchings for LT requests and responses:

```sql
WITH     --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  SAMPLE_DATA(ID, MSG_ID, MSG_TYPE, SENDER, RECIPIENT, CORREL_ID, MRN, DOMAIN, ENV, M_MIN_DATE) AS 
  (
    SELECT 53, '2f5bbec582ff49728d712007e800a5320000018ceaddc90a', 'CD502C-MSG.ECS', 'LV', 'LT', '32344c545652343030303030304630314233000000000000', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('08-JAN-24 20.57.35', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 54, '4145532d32303234303130382d3030303030303031373533', 'CD503C-MSG.ECS', 'LT', 'LV', '2f5bbec582ff49728d712007e800a5320000018ceaddc90a', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('08-JAN-24 20.59.06', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 55, 'a60a0b09007446aa84d2d942a9f6dc600000018ceaea990f', 'CD502C-MSG.ECS', 'LV', 'LT', '32344c545652343030303030304630314233000000000000', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('08-JAN-24 21.11.35', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 56, '4145532d32303234303130382d3030303030303031373539', 'CD503C-MSG.ECS', 'LT', 'LV', 'a60a0b09007446aa84d2d942a9f6dc600000018ceaea990f', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('08-JAN-24 21.13.27', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 57, 'a0e56251c9304cf394f7fc8d393676360000018cece451c9', 'CD502C-MSG.ECS', 'LV', 'LT', '32344c545652343030303030304630314233000000000000', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('09-JAN-24 06.23.57', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 58, '4145532d32303234303130392d3030303030303030303537', 'CD503C-MSG.ECS', 'LT', 'LV', 'a0e56251c9304cf394f7fc8d393676360000018cece451c9', '24LTVR4000000F01B3', 'ECS', 'OP', TO_TIMESTAMP('09-JAN-24 06.25.31', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    --
    SELECT 60, '414d5120424741503220202020202020e4724a6565dfbe26', 'CD502C-MSG.ECS', 'BG', 'IT', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('15-DEC-23 13.34.24', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 61, '414d5120424741503220202020202020e4724a6569dfbe26', 'CD527C-MSG.ECS', 'BG', 'IT', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('15-DEC-23 13.35.21', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 62, '313730323634373334323434333839333832333034363136', 'CD503C-MSG.ECS', 'IT', 'BG', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('15-DEC-23 13.35.43', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 63, '313730323634373336313038323839343137393430353339', 'CD538C-MSG.ECS', 'IT', 'BG', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('15-DEC-23 13.36.02', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 64, '414d5120424741503220202020202020e4724a6579200628', 'CD518C-MSG.ECS', 'BG', 'IT', '323349545156303154303132353536304539000000000000', '23ITQV01T0125560E9', 'ECS', 'OP',  TO_TIMESTAMP('23-DEC-23 07.21.23', 'DD-MON-YY HH24.MI.SS') FROM DUAL
  ), 
  MSG_TYPES(MSG_TYPE_REQ, MSG_TYPE_RES) AS 
  (
    SELECT 'CD502C%', 'CD503C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CD510C%', 'CD591C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CD527C%', 'CD538C%' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CD540C%', 'CD545C%' FROM DUAL
  )
```

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT  REQ.ID "REQ_ID", RES.ID "RES_ID", 
        REQ.RECIPIENT "REQ_RECIPIENT", REQ.SENDER "REQ_SENDER",
        RES.RECIPIENT "RES_RECIPIENT", RES.SENDER "RES_SENDER",
        REQ.M_MIN_DATE "REQ_DATE",
        RES.M_MIN_DATE "RES_DATE"
FROM    SAMPLE_DATA REQ 
LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_DATA RES ON (REQ.MRN = RES.MRN AND 
                              REQ.DOMAIN = RES.DOMAIN AND 
                              REQ.ENV = RES.ENV AND
                              REQ.MSG_ID <> RES.CORREL_ID AND
                              REQ.SENDER <> REQ.RECIPIENT AND
                              REQ.M_MIN_DATE <= RES.M_MIN_DATE  
                             ) 
WHERE EXISTS ( Select 1 From MSG_TYPES Where REQ.MSG_TYPE Like MSG_TYPE_REQ And RES.MSG_TYPE Like MSG_TYPE_RES )
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
    REQ_ID     RES_ID REQ_RECIPIENT REQ_SENDER RES_RECIPIENT RES_SENDER REQ_DATE                    RES_DATE                   
---------- ---------- ------------- ---------- ------------- ---------- --------------------------- ---------------------------
        53         56 LT            LV          LV             LT       08.01.24 20:57:35,000000000 08.01.24 21:13:27,000000000
        53         58 LT            LV          LV             LT       08.01.24 20:57:35,000000000 09.01.24 06:25:31,000000000
        55         58 LT            LV          LV             LT       08.01.24 21:11:35,000000000 09.01.24 06:25:31,000000000
        60         62 IT            BG          BG             IT       15.12.23 13:34:24,000000000 15.12.23 13:35:43,000000000
        61         63 IT            BG          BG             IT       15.12.23 13:35:21,000000000 15.12.23 13:36:02,000000000   */
```

**Addition**:
If you are sure that mutiple REQ vs RES IDs are ok then you could try this

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
Select  SENDER, 
                REQUEST_MSG, 
                MSG_ID_OF_THE_REQUEST_MSG,
                RECIPIENT, 
                CORREL_ID_OF_THE_RESPONSE_MSG,  
                RESPONSE_MSG, 
                MRN, 
                M_MIN_DATE
From  ( SELECT  REQ.ID "REQ_ID", 
                LISTAGG(Distinct REQ.ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By REQ.ID) Over(Partition By RES.ID) "LIST_REQ_ID",
                RES.ID "RES_ID", 
                LISTAGG(Distinct RES.ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By RES.ID) Over(Partition By REQ.ID) "LIST_RES_ID",
                --
                REQ.SENDER, 
                REQ.MSG_TYPE AS "REQUEST_MSG", 
                REQ.MSG_ID AS "MSG_ID_OF_THE_REQUEST_MSG",
                REQ.RECIPIENT, 
                RES.CORREL_ID AS "CORREL_ID_OF_THE_RESPONSE_MSG",  
                coalesce(RES.msg_type,'') AS "RESPONSE_MSG", 
                REQ.MRN, 
                REQ.M_MIN_DATE
            FROM    SAMPLE_DATA REQ 
            LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_DATA RES ON (REQ.MRN = RES.MRN AND 
                            REQ.DOMAIN = RES.DOMAIN AND 
                            REQ.ENV = RES.ENV AND
                            REQ.MSG_ID <> RES.CORREL_ID AND
                            REQ.SENDER <> REQ.RECIPIENT AND
                            REQ.M_MIN_DATE <= RES.M_MIN_DATE  
                           ) 
            WHERE EXISTS ( Select 1 From MSG_TYPES Where REQ.MSG_TYPE Like MSG_TYPE_REQ And RES.MSG_TYPE Like MSG_TYPE_RES )
        )
Where REQ_ID = LIST_REQ_ID And RES_ID = LIST_RES_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

For the REQ_ID = 53, there is a line with RES_ID = 54 and REQ.MSG_ID = RES.CORREL_ID.
So, I don't want to search for invalid match. It is replied correctly.

Similarly, REQ_ID = 55 can be matched correctly with RES_ID = 56 
and REQ_ID = 57 can be matched correctly with RES_ID = 58

So, I don't want these rows to be in output (are matched correctly)

Comment: @prokopis Just posted an addition. Try it, please...

Comment: Thanks a lot it is exactly what I need.
I only modified 
Where REQ_ID = LIST_REQ_ID And RES_ID = LIST_RES_ID 
to
Where TO_CHAR(REQ_ID) = LIST_REQ_ID And TO_CHAR(RES_ID) = LIST_RES_ID